# Postgresql role with no drop table permision

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges

Is it possible to set role with access to one database, with all privileges except to drop tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. If a user can issue CREATE TABLE, it can issue a DROP for that table as well. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS):

> The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked.

And as noted by the [CREATE TABLE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The table will be owned by the user issuing the command.

There is no mechanism to allow a user to create tables that they do not own and therefore cannot drop.